# YouCompleteMe only shows constructors when prefixing with namespace

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

If I have a file where I include a header, YouCompleteMe works very well for code completion except for constructors, the only way that it works is if I use the namespace prefix for that class.

Here is an example, consisting of the header file `some_class.h`:

```
namespace types {
  class some_class {
    public:
      some_class() {};
      some_class(int) {};
      some_class(int, int) {};
      void some_function() {}
  };
}
```

and the main file:

```
#include "some_class.h"   // some_class is in namespace 'types'

using namespace types;

int main() {
   some_class a;      // YouCompleteMe doesn't suggest all the diff ctors I could use
   a.some_function(); // YouCompleteMe suggests autocompletion on my type

   types::some_class b; // Now YouCompleteMe shows all the different ctors I could use
}
```

Why does this happen, is there a way around it, as I don't want to always use the namespace prefix?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what is your workflow. Maybe a short gif with the [keys you press shown on screen](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/screenkey) would be of help.